# Cannot find module 'npmconf' while using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to install/update npm again. I uninstall npm too but again I am getting same error:

```
module.js:340
        throw err;
              ^ Error: Cannot find module 'npmconf'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config.js:16:15)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got answer myself . Here it is :

```
git clone git://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm/scripts
chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```